# Adding script to the Processing Toolbox in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, toolbox

I have a script and I would like to add it to the processing toolbox via Add Script to Toolbox using the Python icon. I received this error and I could not add my script to the processing toolbox.

The error:

> 2023-02-21T12:30:31     WARNING    Could not copy script 'C:/Users/Pagheh/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/scripts/ttt.py'
> 'C:/Users/Pagheh/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/scripts/ttt.py' and 'C:\Users\Pagheh\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\ttt.py' are the same file

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: thank you, with your solution it works

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Try by going in the folder `%APPDATA%\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts`
- Cut the `ttt.py` file then paste it in an other folder
- Retry adding the script under QGIS